# VB ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor CheckboxFor Error "Templates can be used only with field access"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The following code produces the error, "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

```
Line 66:             </div>
Line 67:             <div class="editor-field">
Line 68:                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(m) m.IsCompanyOwner)
Line 69:                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Company)
Line 70:             </div>
```

It points the line 68.

I have already read other posts which said to set the type, which I've done in the model:

```
<DataType(DataType.Text)> _
Public Property IsCompanyOwner As String
```

But, it still gives me the error.  What can I do to fix?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to bind the checkbox to a string.  It must be bound to a bool.  See the documantation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor.aspx)

so IsCompanyOwner should be a Boolean, not a string.

Comment: How do I do that?  My databases needs a string (no options for boolean in SQLCe).

Comment: Then make a new property of type bool and bind the checkbox to that.  Then in the controller, set the string accordingly before persisting.

Comment: Your database should have absolutely no impact on your views or view models.